# Inherited property from parent spring bean has null value

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have this strange case that an inherited property is null when executing a method from the parent class using super() from the child class.

Here are the 2 classes:

```
public class ParentClass {

    private String property;
    
    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void execute() {
    // do something with property;
    }
}

public class ChildClass {

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        super.execute();

        // do something else with property
    }
}
```

Spring application context:

```
<bean id="parentClass" class="com.ParentClass" singleton="false">
    <property name="property" value="value"/>
</bean>

<bean id="childClass" class="com.ChildClass" parent="parentClass" singleton="false">
</bean>
```

When the execute method from ParentClass is called directly property has the value set accordingly.

But when the ChildClass's super.execute() calls the base implementation of execute() from ParentClass the property attribute is null and I cannot understand why.

( It's a legacy project which is using Spring 1.2.7 but still Dependency Injection should work normally)

Comment: I´m not sure but I think this does not work as you want it. You could either duplicate the property line to the child bean or break up the inheritance and use composition instead. Therefore add a "parent" property in the child class.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should work this way... Only in the need of overriding the property value should be added in the child class. At least this is what i get from Spring's documentation : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s06.html

Comment: Well. 1. The doc you linked is for Spring 3.0. 2. The parent class is defined as abstract in the example. Maybe that is causing your issue. Not sure about the singleton flag - could also lead to problems. You also don´t have the "init-method="initialize"". Does the exact example from your link work with your Spring version?

Comment: Maybe it was not the best example to link the documentation for Spring 3 since I'm using Spring 1.X but I think that there aren't that many changes to the basic usage of how Dipendency Injection works in Spring since the 1st version.
This would be the same documentation from the version that I use https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.7/spring-reference.pdf  at 3.5. Abstract and child bean definitions

Comment: It says in the above paragraph that parent beans used as abstract are not instantiated at all. But it doesn't say that parent beans cannot be abstract. 
Also tried without the singleton tag and it runs the same. And in my usage context the beans have to not be singleton. 
Regarding the "init-method" from the example it should not be a problem since that is used only if you want to explicitly use a certain method for initialization, in case it's not provided the default constructor and setters are used to instantiate the bean.

Comment: https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-bean-definition-inheritance-example-using-annotation-and-xml-configuration-with-parent-and-template-with-abstract-attribute There are a lot of examples online which all follow this pattern .. I can't understand why I'm having problems with it.

Comment: Hmmm that´s really strange. Could you maybe create a little github project which I can check with my settings? Unfortunately I don´t have the time right now to setup a little example...

Comment: I'm having the same problem. However my parent classes are abstract.

Comment: ChildClass does not extend ParentClass in your code.  I see no relationship between these two classes - no IS-A by inheritance, no HAS-A by composition.  Perhaps that is why Spring doesn't either.